# Overlap image over two rows in a listview

Tags: android, image, overlay, android-listview

I need create a listview with pinned overlay image over upper row and next row, like image example below.

[image: image pinned a row and overlaped over row1 and row2]

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

set the Layout parameters of image, ie size not exceed to the parent view

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(30, 30);
yourImageView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

Comment: Sorry @jazz, but I use that code, and appear a ClassCastException: `LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(10, 10);
  ImageView iv = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.first_image);
  
  iv.setLayoutParams(lp);`